# Proof that spectrum of a matrix is subset of the positive real numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, diagonalization

So my given problem is:

$Let\,\, A \in \mathbb{C}^{n \,\times \,n}\,\, be\,\, such\,\, that\,\,\\ \forall x\in \mathbb{C}^n : \langle\,Ax,x\rangle \geq 0 \\ where \,\, \langle\,\cdot,\cdot\rangle \,\, is \,\, the \,\, standard \,\, inner \,\, product \,\, of \,\, \mathbb{C}^n.\,\, Show \,\, that\,\,\\ spec(A) \subset [0, \infty).$

Know I don't have any approach how to tackle the problem.

Thank you in advance

$\textbf{EDIT:}$

I came this far:

Let $\lambda$ be e-value of A and x the corresponding e-vector.

$Ax = \lambda x \,\,\, multiply \,\, x^T\\ x^TAx = \lambda x^Tx$

The left hand side of the equation is greater or equal to zero since

$x^TAx=\langle\,Ax,x\rangle \geq 0$

Then

$ = \lambda \sum_{i=1}^{n} x^{2}_i $

Since $x^Tx=\sum_{i=1}^{n} x^{2}_i$

The sum is positive therefore $\lambda$ has to be greater or equal to 0 so that the whole term is greater or equal to zero.

But now I dont know how to show that all eigenvalues are real.

Comment: Think about eigenvectors.

Comment: I mean I know that it has to do with the eigenvectors since I'm supposed to show that the set of all eigenvalues is a subset of the positive real numbers. I was looking for some more specific information.

Comment: Start with the eigenvector equation and see if you can use that to figure something out about the eigenvalue.

Comment: @tch alright but I guess I have to use the information with the standard inner product but I don't know where and how.

Comment: This seems a lot like a homework problem so I'm hesitant to give more hints without an explanation of what you have tried and why it hasn't worked.

Comment: Yea it is you are right I will try out a bit more

Comment: The crucial information is that $\langle Ax,x \rangle $ is real for all $x$.

Comment: @tch I came this far:

Let $\lambda$ be e-value of A and x the corresponding e-vector. 

$Ax = \lambda x \
multiply x^T\\ x^TAx = \lambda x^Tx$

The left hand side of the equation is greater or equal to zero since 

$x^TAx=\langle\,Ax,x\rangle \geq 0$

Then 

$ = \lambda \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} x^{2}_i $

Since $x^Tx=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} x^{2}_i$

The sum is positive therefore $\lambda$ has to be greater or equal to 0 so that the whole term is greater or equal to zero.


But now I dont know how to show that all eigenvalues are real.

Comment: @copper.hat can you explain to me why it is real for all x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If

$\lambda \in \text{spec}(A), \tag 0$

we have a vector $x \in \Bbb C^n$ such that

$Ax = \lambda x, \; x \ne 0; \tag 1$

then

$\bar \lambda \langle x, x \rangle = \langle \lambda x, x \rangle = \langle Ax, x \rangle \ge 0; \tag 2$

we recall that the assertion $\langle Ax, x \rangle \ge 0$ (tacitly, by definition) implies $\langle Ax, x \rangle \in [0, \infty) \subset \Bbb R$, and since

$0 \ne \langle x, x \rangle \in (0, \infty) \subset \Bbb R, \tag 3$

(2) yields

$0 \le \bar \lambda \in [0, \infty) \subset \Bbb R; \tag 4$

now

$\bar \lambda \in [0, \infty) \subset \Bbb R \Longleftrightarrow \lambda \in [0, \infty) \subset \Bbb R; \tag 5$

therefore

$\text{spec}(A) \subset [0, \infty), \tag 6$

as was to be shown. $OE\Delta$.

Comment: what does that $\lambda$ with the bar above denote? The complex conjugate of $\lambda$?

Comment: @FoYoungArealLo:  yes, $\bar \lambda$ is as you say!

Comment: Ok, can you explain to me why $\bar{\lambda} \langle\,x,x\rangle = \langle\,\lambda x,x\rangle $ holds? I would expect it to be $\bar{\lambda} \langle\,x,x\rangle = \langle\,\bar{\lambda} x,x\rangle$

Comment: @FoYoungArealLo:  it depends on how one defines the standard inner product on $\Bbb C^n$; one argument always gets conjugated; I chose the first.  $\langle u, v \rangle = \sum \bar u_i v_i$ where $u = (u_1, \ldots, u_n)$ etc.

Comment: In my original post I put in an edit in which I show my approach to proof the statement. Maybe you could have a look on it and tell me what I have to do now or what I did wrong